# Where is the call to std::map::operator[] in this code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dictionary

I have the following typedef's in my code:

```
typedef unsigned long int ulint;
typedef std::map<ulint, particle> mapType;
typedef std::vector< std::vector<mapType> > mapGridType;
```

`particle` is a custom class with no default constructor.

VS2008 gives me an error in this code:

```
std::set<ulint> gridOM::ids(int filter)
{
    std::set<ulint> result;
    ulint curId;
    for ( int i = 0; i < _dimx; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < _dimy; ++j ) {
            // next line is reported to be erroneous
            for ( mapType::iterator cur = objectMap[i][j].begin(); cur != objectMap[i][j].end(); ++cur )
            {
                curId = (*cur).first;
                if ( (isStatic(curId) && filter != 2) || (!isStatic(curId) && filter != 1) )
                {
                    result.insert(curId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`objectMap` is an object of `mapGridType`. The error reads:

```
error C2512: 'gridOM::particle::particle' : no appropriate default constructor available
while compiling class template member function 'gridOM::particle &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const unsigned long &)'  
        with  
        [  
            _Kty=ulint,  
            _Ty=gridOM::particle  
        ]  
        .\gridOM.cpp(114) : see reference to class template   instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'   being compiled  
        with  
        [  
            _Kty=ulint,  
            _Ty=gridOM::particle  
        ]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the above code should not be making calls to `map::operator[]` at all. The first `operator[]` call is made to `vector< vector<mapType> >` and returns a `vector<mapType>`, the second is made to `vector<mapType>` and returns a `mapType` aka a `map<ulint, particle>`, and I only call `begin()` and `end` on that map. So why do I get an error trying to compile the `operator[]` for `map`?

Comment: Could you provide definition for `objectMap`?

Comment: You don't think perhaps the map's iterators use operator[] internally when dereferenced?

Comment: `objectMap` is of type `mapGridType` (edited the question)

Comment: The code you have posted compiles for me on VS2008 SP1. Are you sure the error is on the line with the for? Because even when I tried to use operator [] of the map and therefore generate the error, I only got error in map itself, no mention of my source or line number there. I recommend commenting out parts of your program until you find exactly where's your problem

Comment: @kts: btw, it makes no sense for an iterator to be using operator[] for map. First, operator[] performs a map-search with O(NlogN) complexity which would be insanely slow for a dereference operation. Second, iterators can, should and actually do access the internal map tree structure - they just don't need operator[]. Third, as mentioned, operator[] requires default-constructable value types while map in general doesn't.

Comment: &sbk: the Error List only points to map.cpp for me too, but the Output window has a more detailed description of the error, which is what I pasted. As you can see, it points to line 144 in gridOM.cpp, which is the line with the `for`.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler isn't going off-by-one line on the error message? The line in question looks ok but is there an adjacent line that might be using operator []? It's hard to tell with such a small snippet of the code.

Comment: @Mark: there are no '[' or ']' characters anywhere else in the method that the offending line is in, and no references to any maps. I'll paste the entire method in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed. It turns out that I did in fact make the coding mistake of writing a call to `operator[]`, but it was hundreds of lines further down in the source file from where the error was reported. Apparently VS just pointed me to the first usage of a variable of `mapType` instead of the actual point where it tried to instantiate the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of my answer. But when you instanciate a template, the compiler implements all the functions defined in the template (even if they aren't used). So  you get the error, even if there is no use of the function.

Could you give the complete error message?

**EDIT** With the full error message, you get the problem! As you told, your object has no default constructor. However, in order to use a map, you need the default constructor (as it is required by the function operator[] in order to build an instance when using a new key), even if you don't use the function, it will be implemented by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally left off the first line of the error. Edited.

Comment: Not true. Each class template definition in reality *defines* a template for the class type itself and *declares* a bunch of independent templates for its member functions. (Yes, each member function is an independent template). When you instantiate class template, member functions *don't* get immediately instantiated, until you actually call them or force their instantiation in some other way. So, until you actually call `std::map<>::operator[]` it must *not* get instantiated, even if you already instantiated `std::map<>` itself.

Comment: Regarding your edit. I'm actually editing code that was working before. The typedef's were the same, and the code compiled and ran even with no default constructor for `particle`. I'm fairly sure that templates get instantiated on a per-method basis rather than per-class: that is, the compiler wouldn't try to instantiate `map::operator[]` unless I made a call to it.

Comment: They're usually instantiated per-method, but you could cause all method to be instantiated using the statement `template std::map<ulint, particle>;`

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is perfectly fine and compiles without any errors at the `for` line in GCC and Comeau (Onlie) compilers. Right now I have no way to try it in VS2008 specifically, unfortunately.

If the error is indeed triggered by the `for` line, I'd suspect a problem in the compiler. There's a chance that the implementation of `std::map<>::begin()` or `std::map<>::end()` somehow depends on `std::map<>::operator[]()` in VS2008, but that would be rather strange.